# Javascript adding a hidden field

Tags: javascript

I want to add a hidden field for each checkbox that is checked on a form.

This is my form :

```
<form action="managementSales" method="post" name="saleByItems">
Results in Tracks
<table id="pendingTable" border="1">
<tr>
  <th>Id</th>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>artist</th>
  <th>List Price</th>
  <th>Sale Price</th>
</tr>
<c:forEach var="t" items="${tracks}">
<tr>
    <td><c:out value="${t.trackId}" /></td>
    <td><c:out value="${t.trackTitle}" /></td>
    <td><c:out value="${t.artist}" /></td>
    <td><c:out value="${t.listPrice}" /></td>
    <td><c:out value="${t.salePrice}" /></td>
    <td class="radioBox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkTrack" value="${t.trackId}"></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>

<button onclick="validate()" class="button" name="saveChange" id="saveChange">Save</button>
    </form>
```

and then my javascript:

```
            <script type='text/javascript'>
            function validate() {
                var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input'), inputsLength = inputs.length;

                for ( var i = 0; i < inputsLength; i++) 
                {
                    var cpt=1;
                    if (inputs[i].name == 'checkTrack' && inputs[i].checked) 
                    {
                        document.getElementById('saveChange').innerHTML = '<input type="hidden" value="'+inputs[i].value+'" name="trackId_'+cpt+'">';
                        cpt++;
                    }

                }


                for ( var j = 0; j < inputsLength; j++) 
                {
                    var cpt2=1;
                    if (inputs[j].type == 'checkAlbum' && inputs[j].checked) 
                    {
                        document.getElementById('saveChange').innerHTML = '<input type="hidden" value="'+inputs[j].value+'" name="albumId_'+cpt2+'">';
                        cpt2++;
                    }
                }
            }
```

The problem is that even if I change the type to text to see if something changes nothing happens

Comment: Debug the JavaScript to see what's failing. Modern web-browsers offer an integrated developer tool for this.

Comment: Are you trying to add hidden element inside button element?.....If yes, you cant do that. 'Element input cannot be nested inside element button' Add hidden element to html body/form/div instead.

Comment: can i know why you need hidden field for each checkbox ??

Comment: Why you need input hidden to have the values of checkboxs ? .... when the form submitted there array send to server with checked data, and you can call it : request .getParameterValues("checkTrack");

Comment: I want to put this into hidden input to send the list of trackId checked by the admin to my servlet

Comment: @Mohamed Ali, what do you mean by checkTrack ?

Comment: @SebDev43 checkTrack  is the name of input check boxes. in your page after render there are many check boxes with the same name and after submit it will send the checked with the name checkTrack as array so in your servlet you will get them from request by : request .getParameterValues("checkTrack");

Comment: So i have to set for each check boxes the attribute name at "checkTrack" ?

Comment: But i don't understand one thing, How i can acces to each value of checkBox checked?
Like this :

    int[] checkBox = request.getParameterValues("checkTrack");

Comment: It's okay i understand now and the problem is solved, rather than put trackId in hidden input, i get this trackId from my servlet  with request.getParameterValues("checkTrack"); which return an array of string which contained all values contained in the checkbox Checked. Thanks Mohamed Ali and others of course